# kendo.tostring does not format number when value is string

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using `kendo.toString()` method to format string as [documented here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting#types-of-number-formats)
So for example

```
   kendo.culture("en-US");
   kendo.toString(5000, "n")
```

returns `5,000`

However if i pass string parameter then it does not work

```
   kendo.culture("en-US");
   kendo.toString("5000", "n")
```

returns `5000`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpcz3478/1/)

Answer (score 2):

To format a number with `kendo.toString()` you should pass a number and not a string

You can simply parse it:

```
var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
val = kendo.toString(val, "n")
```

See updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f3wku3p/)

---

See `kendo.toString()` logic

**From kendo.all.js:**

```
var toString = function (value, fmt, culture) {
  if (fmt) {
    if (objectToString.call(value) === '[object Date]') {
      return formatDate(value, fmt, culture);
        } else if (typeof value === NUMBER) {
          return formatNumber(value, fmt, culture);
        }
    }
    return value !== undefined ? value : '';
  };
}
```

In case `value` is a string, `toString()` will echo it back

Comment: Thanks. However the negative number is not shown brackets. for `en-US` culture negative numbers should be shown in brackets https://jsfiddle.net/cpcz3478/10/

Comment: Actually this is exactly the expected behavior.. Take a look at [Kendo's Culture docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/definecultureinfo). It has the code for `en-US` culture definition and it clearly states the format for negative numbers is `-n`. You can see it under `numberFormat: {` written: `pattern: ["-n"],`. Anyway one can override this behavior by changing the file but this is way out of this question's scope already. Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: Just to further comment on the negative number formatting: en-US format for negative *numbers* is "-n",  HOWEVER the format for negative *currency* is "($n)".  If you toString(val, "c") you would get the brackets(and a $).  If you want a "(n)" format for non-currency numbers, you would have to override the default format defined by the culture.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that doing the following seemed to work, so I guess that particular method does not support string inputs.

```
kendo.culture("en-US");
$("#testnumber").text(kendo.toString(5000,"n"))

$("#myinput").change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();

   val = kendo.toString(parseFloat(val), "n")
   $(this).val(val);

})
```